# Tabla sys.sql_logins en SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

tabla **sys.sql_logins** en **SQL Server 2000** validación de la siguiente query en SQL Server 2000;

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(name, 10) name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN is_disabled = 1 THEN  'No' 
        WHEN is_disabled = 0 THEN 'Si' 
    END [¿Habilitado?], 
    RIGHT(default_database_name,15) BD 
    FROM **sys.sql_logins** 
    WHERE name = 'SA' 
    AND is_disabled = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar la vista de sistema `dbo.syslogins` de la base de datos `master`. Sin embargo, no todas las columnas de la vista `sys.sql_logins` están disponibles en esta vista más antigua (por ejemplo, `is_disabled` ya no existe, por lo que tendrías que revisar cuál columna es la cuál debes usar para este filtro) y otras columnas tienen diferente nombre:

```
SELECT  RIGHT(name, 10) name, 
        RIGHT(dbname,15) BD 
FROM master.dbo.syslogins
WHERE sysadmin = 1 --name = 'SA';
```

Comment: Me ayudo mucho tu respuesta .

Answer (score 0):

sys.sql_logins  = syslogins, 
hasaccess = 1 **(se ha concedido acceso al servidor.)**

**Consulta Final:**

```
 SELECT  
 RIGHT(name, 30) name,  
 CASE  
     WHEN hasaccess = 1 THEN  'SI'  
     WHEN hasaccess = 0 THEN 'NO'  
     END AS [¿Habilitado?],  
  RIGHT(dbname,15) BD  
  FROM  
  syslogins  
  WHERE sysadmin = 1
```